# call the last elapsed time in java

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm making a game with libgdx in android Studio. In this game the score is the same as the elapsed time (made with ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 100)). I'm also using different classes as states (MenuState, PlayState and  GameOverState)...

```
public class PlayState extends State {

    long startTime;

    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private BitmapFont font;

    public PlayState(GameStateManager gsm) {
        super(gsm);
        cam.setToOrtho(false, Game.WIDTH, Game.HEIGHT);
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("text.fnt"), Gdx.files.internal("text.png"), false);
        font.getData().setScale(.5f, .5f);
    }

    @Override
    protected void handleInput() {

    }

     @Override
    public void update(float dt) {

    }

    @Override
    public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
        sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
        System.out.println("Score = " + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 100));

        batch.begin();
        font.draw(batch, "Score: " + Float.toString((Float) ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 100f)), 20, 470);
        font.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        bg.dispose();
        bird.dispose();
        ground.dispose();
        batch.dispose();
        font.dispose();
        for(Tube tube : tubes)
            tube.dispose();
        for(Cloud cloud : clouds)
            cloud.dispose();
        //stage.dispose();
        System.out.println("Play State Disposed");
    }

    private void updateGround() {
        if(cam.position.x - (cam.viewportWidth / 2) > groundPos1.x + ground.getWidth())
            groundPos1.add(ground.getWidth() * 2, 0);
        if(cam.position.x - (cam.viewportWidth / 2) > groundPos2.x + ground.getWidth())
            groundPos2.add(ground.getWidth() * 2, 0);
    }
}
```

I want to get the last score in GameOverState and print it on the screen...
Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll need to store the score in a variable instead of just printing it as a string.

Then, since the PlayState and GameOverState don't know about each other, you can use GameStateManager to get the score variable from PlayState and pass it to GameOverState which can then print it to the screen.

I can't give any specific code since I don't know how the rest of your classes are laid out, but that's the general idea.